# When I read does'nt implement all the specification what does it mean?

Tags: tomcat, glassfish

When I read that glassfish supports all of the Java EE API specifications and tomcat does not, does that mean I cannot perform some functionality on tomcat that I can using glassfish?

Comment: Yes, it means just that. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm wondering what server to use for an app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/java_app/tomcat6/tomcat6_apache.htm

Tomcat 6 supports the Servlet and JSP APIs, whereas Java EE consists of those plus other APIs. You'll need to check which EE APIs your code actually uses.